# NuxtJS Typescript click.native 'cannot read property 'test' of null'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have created a custom navbar in nuxtjs and if i want to close the navbar on clicking a n-link i get this error:  Cannot read property 'test' of null.
I am using nuxt-property-decorator dependency.

My code:

```
<template>
  <!-- MOBILE NAVBAR -->
  <nav class="navbar">
    <mq-layout mq="sm" class="navbar-wrapper" :class="$mq">
      <button class="navbar-dropdown-button-mobile" @click="this.toggleDropdownMenu"> <!-- set dropdown enabled / disabled -->
        <picture>
          <img
            class="navbar-dropdown-img-mobile"
            src="@/assets/icons/dropdown_menu_button.png"
            alt="Menu"
          />
        </picture>
      </button>
    </mq-layout>
    <!-- ... Other Code -->
    <!-- DROPDOWN -->
    <mq-layout mq="sm" class="navbar-dropdown-menu-mobile" v-if="this.showDropdownMenu"> <!-- show/hide dropdown depending on showDropDownMenu boolean  -->
      <n-link class="navbar-link-mobile" :class="$mq" to="/" prefetch>LINK</n-link>
      <n-link class="navbar-link-mobile" :class="$mq" @click.native="this.test" to="/pricing" prefetch>LINK</n-link> <!-- This @click.native thorws this error -->
      <n-link class="navbar-link-mobile" :class="$mq" to="/documentation" prefetch>LINK</n-link>
      <n-link class="navbar-link-mobile" :class="$mq" to="/support" prefetch>LINK</n-link>
    </mq-layout>
    <!-- ... Other Code -->
  </nav>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Component } from 'nuxt-property-decorator';

@Component({})
export default class NavbarComponent extends Vue {
  protected showDropdownMenu: boolean = false;

  protected toggleDropdownMenu() {
    this.showDropdownMenu = !this.showDropdownMenu;
  }

  test() {
    console.log("HIIIIII")
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: did you try out `@click.native="test"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `this` in template of your Vue files.

```
<n-link class="navbar-link-mobile" :class="$mq" @click.native="test" to="/pricing" prefetch>LINK</n-link>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html